# Is there a definition for the concept of the mass of a sequence of measures concentrating on a subset?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, definition

I have been thinking about the following concept:

Let $X$ be a topological space, $(X, \mathcal{B}_X, \mu)$
be a measure space, $\mathcal{P}(X)$ the set of probability measures on $(X, \mathcal{B}_X)$, $(\mu_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathcal{P}(X) $ and $E \in \mathcal{A}$.

Is there a term to describe the following property:

for each $U \in \mathcal{N}_{E}$ (neighborhood of $E$), $\mu_n(U^c) \rightarrow 0$

It looks like weak convergence type of property. Naturally I would like to refer to it as "$(\mu_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ concentrating on $E$", but I think that is already taken.